# Statsd dying silently

Tags: graphite, statsd

Statsd being started by Chef is dying. I believe I have isolated the problem away from Chef as the INIT script Chef is calling is doing what it is suppose to. I have turned debug on for statsd and in the log the following is the last messages before dying:

```
15 Oct 11:17:39 - reading config file: /etc/statsd/config.js
15 Oct 11:17:39 - server is up
15 Oct 11:17:39 - DEBUG: Loading backend: ./backends/graphite
```

I am absolutely stumped; nothing in /var/log/messages, nothing in the error log. Any idea if statsd requires certain services up and running?

Comment: What happens when you run it from the console?

Answer (score 1):

StatsD doesn't require any specific services to run. You can also set `dumpMessages` to true in the config to have it log all messages that are incoming to get a picture of what's happening. Does it send any data to Graphite during the time it's up? If you continue having problems, there is also #statsd on Freenode IRC where a lot of people are idling who know a thing or two about StatsD.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue. I found [this page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-statsd-to-collect-arbitrary-stats-for-graphite-on-ubuntu-14-04) very informative. I took only the part to package my statsd with its backends (changed package files a bit) and installed the created package to make it a daemon.

Hope this helps.